# .map in react from this.state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to return elements in a `.map` function from the React State in a Class component but got TypeError: this.state.imagesResponse.photos.photo is not a function, so I wonder I'm doing something wrong.

Also, I tested it into the console and works as expected. Maybe I'm missing something stupid.

Here is my example:

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class HomeContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            imagesResponse: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=THE_API_KEY&text=architectural+design&sort=faves&extras=description%2C+url_q&per_page=10&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`)
            .then(res => this.setState({ imagesResponse: res.data }));
    }

    render() {
            return (
                <section className="Container">
                    <div className="Grid">
                        { this.state.imagesResponse.photos.photo.map((item, index) =>
                            <Link className="GridItem" to={`/detail/${item.id}`}  key={index} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(https://live.staticflickr.com/${item.server}/${item.id}_${item.secret}_q.jpg)` }} as="article">
                                <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                            </Link>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </section>
            )
    }
}

export default HomeContainer;
```

And `this.state.imagesResponse` is:

```
const imagesResponse = {
  "photos": {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 143979,
    "perpage": 10,
    "total": "1439787",
    "photo": [
      {
        "id": "50854721563",
        "owner": "30255101@N08",
        "secret": "b2f6251d8b",
        "server": "65535",
        "farm": 66,
        "title": "Welbeck",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0,
        "description": {
          "_content": "Designed for Debenhams..."
        },
        "url_q": "https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50854721563_b2f6251d8b_q.jpg",
        "height_q": 150,
        "width_q": 150
      },
      {
        "id": "50855414036",
        "owner": "87583925@N00",
        "secret": "4da621d7d6",
        "server": "65535",
        "farm": 66,
        "title": "Wakefield",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0,
        "description": {
          "_content": "County Hall..."
        },
        "url_q": "https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50855414036_4da621d7d6_q.jpg",
        "height_q": 150,
        "width_q": 150
      },
    ]
  },
  "stat": "ok"
}
```

If I map like so in the console works but not in the React `.map` function:

`imagesResponse.photos.photo.map(item => console.log(item))`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your initial state sets `imagesResponse` to `[]`. But then you're trying to use `imagesResponse.photos`. Arrays don't have a `photos` property. Your initial state should be `this.state = {imagesResponse: {photos: {photo: []}}}`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial state sets `imagesResponse` to `[]`. But then you're trying to use `imagesResponse.photos`. Arrays don't have a `photos` property.

Based on the data you say you receive later, your initial state should be:

```
this.state = {
    imagesResponse: {
        photos: {
            photo: [],
        },
    },
};
```

*(You may want more of the structure than that (`page`, `pages`, `total`, ...), but that's enough to deal with the error you asked about.)*

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the initial state `imagesResponse: []` of imageResponse which is an `array`

However, you call `this.state.imagesResponse.photos.photo.map(func)` in `render()`

It may work you change the initial state with

```js
imagesResponse: {
    photos: {
        photo: [],
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a initial state value you can just check if such a field exists.

```ts
render() {
    const {imagesResponse} = this.state;

    return (
        <section className="Container">
            <div className="Grid">
                { imagesResponse.photos && 
                  imagesResponse.photos.photo && 
                  imagesResponse.photos.photo.map((item, index) =>
                    <Link 
                       className="GridItem" to={`/detail/${item.id}`}  key={index} 
                       style={{ 
                             backgroundImage: `url(https://live.staticflickr.com/${item.server}/${item.id}_${item.secret}_q.jpg)` }} as="article">
                         <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                    </Link>
                )}
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```